# Is there a way to re-subscribe after unsubscribing RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Here is a sample code that subscribes to Http request and cancels it upon mouse click on the page. I would like to resubscribe if I perform click once again.

How can I toggle subscription? 
[FIDDLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4lbxcw)

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private http:HttpClient){
}

flag=true;
documentclick = fromEvent(document, 'click');

 private data = {
    name:  'Samurai',
    profession:  'Developer'
  };
  ngOnInit(){

    let subscription:Subscription = this.getGoogle()   )
    .subscribe((res)=> {
     console.log(res);
   })

    this.documentclick.subscribe( e=>{
      if(this.flag){
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
      else{
        subscription = this.getGoogle().subscribe((res)=> {
          console.log(res);
        });
      }
      this.flag != this.flag;

    });
  }

getGoogle(): Observable<any> {
    return   this.http.get( 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').pipe ( delay( 2000 ) )
  }

}
```

With the above code I am able to cancel the request if I click the page within 2 seconds. But I am not able to subscribe again on clicking again.

Also, it would be great if someone could tell me if I am really cancelling the http request with unsubscribe()? Or is it just an illusion? Will the request hit the server if I unsubscribe withing 2 seconds?

Comment: Actually you don't have to unsubscribe the http requests in angular, Because they are completed automatically once the server responds to that request. You can put console.log in the `complete property` in your `subscribe fn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a logic error, just a typo I think.

```
this.flag != this.flag;
```

You probably meant

```
this.flag = !this.flag;
```

By the way (unrelated to your issue) your method of getting document clicks is a non-angular way and you may run into issues with the page not updating. Consider using a HostListener instead:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
clicked(event) {
    ..
}
```

Unsubscribing from the HTTP request should cancel the request. However, you have no guaranteed way of knowing if the request actually went through to the server, or not - the server may have already replied by the time you unsubscribed.

Here's a cleaned-up stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzlzcf

Comment: Oh! Yes! How could I have missed that! I The reason why I used ` documentclick = 
 fromEvent(document, 'click');` is because I wanted to get observable in a variable.

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense; I'm really not sure why you would want to do that, it doesn't serve any purpose. See my cleaned stackblitz, I've fixed a couple of other minor issues too.

Comment: I did that because I was playing around with various rxjs operators such as mere Map , exhaustMap  etc. I needed to create two observable to use them. I am new to rxjs and stuff so bear with me if I sound like a noob.

Comment: Oh absolutely, if it's for your own research and experimentation, then by all means go nuts. :) (By the way. please don't forget to mark the question as answered if all is good!)